# How to search for items with multiple "-" in excel or VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of item numbers (100K) like this:

[image]

Some of the items have format like **SAG571A-244-4** (thousands) which need to be filtered so I can delete them and only keep the items that have **ONE** hyphen per SKU. How can I isolate the items that have two instances of **"-"** in it's SKU? I'm open to solutions within Excel or using VBA as well.

Native text filters don't seem to be capable of this. I'm stumped.

Comment: Iterate backwards and check if the length minus the length after the `-` have been removed is > 1.  `If Len(Str) - Len(Replace(Str,"-",""))>1 then`

Comment: ubound(split(item, "-")) > 1

Comment: In VBA you can use the like operator: `s Like "*-*-*"` will be true only of strings which have at least two hyphens.

Comment: Do you think it's possible as a custom text filter? It doesn't seem to be working for me. I tried `s Like "*-*-*"` Maybe an example would help ..

Comment: A quick experiment shows that `"*-*-*"` seems to work for a custom text filter. Just use show rows where sku equal to `*-*-*` (without the literal quote marks if entering this from the Excel interface rather than VBA).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per John Coleman's comment, `"*-*-*"` can be used to isolate strings that have at least two dashes in them.

I would add that if you're entering them as a custom text filter, you should lose the double quotes (so just `*-*-*`) as otherwise the field seems to interpret the quotes literally.

Seems to work for me.

[image: Output]

Comment: An animated gif showing just how. What's not to like? (+1)

Comment: Excellent answer, +1 and accepted, thanks @chillin!

Answer (score 0):

If you want just an excel formula to verify this and give you a result of the number of hyphens (0, 1, or 2+), here is one:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("-",A1)),"0",IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("-",A1,IFERROR(SEARCH("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))),"1","2+"))
```

Replace A1 with your relevant column, then fill down. This is kind of a terrible way to do this performance wise, but you avoid using VBA and possibly xlsm files.

The code first checks to see if there is one hyphen, then if there is it checks to see if there is another hyphen after the position the first one was found. Looking for multiple hyphens in this manner is cumbersome and I don't recommend it.

Comment: You can test for 2 (or more) hyphens with the shorter formula:  `=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))>1`  which will return `TRUE` if there are 2 (or more) hyphens.